# How is it possible to search on Google without HTTPS?

Tags: google-search, https

I could not find a way to obtain the searched keywords of the query. Even on a private-tab `www.google.com` is redirected to `https://www.google.com`.

But `wget http://www.google.com` does not redirect to HTTPS

Should it be possible on an old browser or a non graphical browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try visiting http://www.google.com/?nord=1 if you don't want to be redirected to HTTPS version

Comment: It seems like this no longer works

Answer (score 0):

You can, as Nima suggested, browse to http://www.google.com/?nord=1, or add `?nord=1` after your query. (Read a little more [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.se/2013/11/how-to-disable-google-secure-search.html).)

Another, more advanced but persistent, way is to edit your DNS entry for Google, as explained [here](http://www.seroundtable.com/turn-off-google-ssl-search-17477.html).
If you use the DNS server `nosslsearch.google.com` Google won't server SLL search results.